# Creating Stacked chart.js graph from array

Tags: javascript, php, json, chart.js

I would like to create a stacked graph of data.
The data is bottle feeds for each day.

Eg. I have this data

```
0:{date: "2017-12-19", 2017-12-19 22:46:00: 341}
1:{date: "2017-12-30", 2017-12-30 10:30:00: 199, 2017-12-30 14:00:00: 142, 2017-12-30 19:18:00: 199, 2017-12-30 17:00:00: 200}
2:{date: "2017-12-31", 2017-12-31 15:43:00: 341, 2017-12-31 16:30:00: 199}
3:{date: "2018-01-01", 2018-01-01 19:09:00: 199, 2018-01-01 06:00:00: 170, 2018-01-01 11:30:00: 170, 2018-01-01 09:00:00: 170}
```

So a json array. The first key value is the date of the feeds.
The rest are the time of day and the amount for that feed.
I would like my chart js to to have 4 labels (each date value) 
and the stacked data to be the time of day and the amount for each day (date).

a: Do I have my data in the correct format?
b: how do i dynamically add this data to chart.js?
Can I loop over each one and push it in?  As sometimes there may be data from 30 dates, for example..

Thanks.

Comment: The data is store in a JS object BTW.

Comment: It's always going to just be 4 dates?

Comment: Hi. No could be up to 30

Comment: So you want to have "4 labels (each date value)" but you can have up to 30 dates? So how do you get 4 labels based on 30 dates? If your 4 labels was an example then ok...but if not and you want 30 labels your chart is going to be so congested that it's not going to be readable.

Comment: Ok. The example I give has 4 separate dates. But there could be 30, 40 etc many dates. Each with a varying number of times and amounts. Does that make sense?

Comment: Gotcha. And I was misquoted on the labels, I was thinking about the legend but I'm guessing/hoping that will be hidden...

Comment: Any ideas then?

Answer (score 0):

I think best to use this structure:

```
0:{date: "2017-12-19", [
    {time: "2017-12-19 22:46:00", feeds: 341}
]}
1:{date: "2017-12-30", [
    {time: "2017-12-30 10:30:00", feeds: 199}, 
    {time: "2017-12-30 14:00:00", feeds: 142}, 
    {time: "2017-12-30 19:18:00", feeds: 199}, 
    {time: "2017-12-30 17:00:00", feeds: 200}
]}
2:{date: "2017-12-31", [
    {time: "2017-12-31 15:43:00", feeds: 341}, 
    {time: "2017-12-31 16:30:00", feeds: 199}
]}
3:{date: "2018-01-01", [
    {time: "2018-01-01 19:09:00", feeds: 199}, 
    {time: "2018-01-01 06:00:00", feeds: 170}, 
    {time: "2018-01-01 11:30:00", feeds: 170}, 
    {time: "2018-01-01 09:00:00", feeds: 170}
]}
```

Comment: Missing opening bracket for your times in `3:..`

Comment: Thank. Correct answer

Comment: Thanks j. Litvak. How do I then pass this data into chart.js?  That's my main issue.  I can organise the data whichever way works best.

Comment: insert this Json object to `data.data` in new chart declaration (initialisation) of show me you js and php code